# Scale text in WPF

Tags: wpf, text, scale

How can I automatically scale text inside a control based on the control's size but always make sure it's readable (that is, I want the font size stays between 9pt and 30pt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ScaleTransform.
In order to understand how to calculate the scale size you may refer to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d73c9eb2-9c68-428d-b99b-d23d0c62c095/

Answer (score 2):

The [ViewBox](http://wesaday.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/wpf-text-scaling/) can help with this, but I'm not sure about keeping the font size within a range.  You can probably accomplish this roughly with `MinHeight` and `MinWidth`.

Comment: No it doesn't. If viewbox has max height or max width, long text will look really small.